# Eigenvalues of SSOR Update Matrix for Symmetric A

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider solving $Ax=b$ iteratively using symmetric successive over-relaxation (SSOR).  Following Demmel (1997, p299), the update matrix for the scheme is:
$$
 R = (I - \omega U)^{-1}((1 - \omega)I + \omega L)\cdot (I - \omega L)^{-1}((1 - \omega)I + \omega U)
$$
where $A = D - \tilde{L} - \tilde{U} = D(I - L - U)$ with $D$ being diagonal portion of $A$, $\tilde{L}$ the negative of the strictly lower triangular portion, and $\tilde{U}$ the negative strictly upper triangular portion.

The goal is to show the eigenvalues of $R$ are real if $A = A^T$.  Demmel proceeds by claiming the similar matrix $(I - \omega U)R(1 - \omega U)^{-1}$ is symmetric from which the claim follows trivially.  However, he also states $U = L^T$ which I believe to be incorrect as $L^T = (D^{-1}\tilde{L})^T = \tilde{L}^TD^{-T}=\tilde{U}D^{-1} \neq D^{-1}\tilde{U}=U$.

Does anyone know how this can be shown in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is probably a mistake and the statemenet should be proven based on the assumption that $\bar{L}^T=\bar{U}$ instead. It still can be done though.

We have that (with $\alpha:=\omega-2$ to keep it shorter)
$$
\begin{split}
R
&=
I
+\alpha^2(I-\omega U)^{-1}(I-\omega L)^{-1}
+\alpha(I-\omega U)^{-1}\\
&+\alpha(I-\omega U)^{-1}(I-\omega L)^{-1}(I-\omega U).
\end{split}
$$
Now in terms of $D$, $\bar{L}$, and $\bar{U}$, we have
$I-\omega L=D^{-1}(D-\omega\bar{L})$, $I-\omega U=D^{-1}(D-\omega\bar{U})$, and
$$
\begin{split}
R
&=
I
+\alpha^2(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}D(D-\omega \bar{L})^{-1}D
+\alpha(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}D\\
&+\alpha(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}D(D-\omega \bar{L})^{-1}(D-\omega \bar{U}).
\end{split}
$$
Now we get
$$
\begin{split}
(D-\omega \bar{U})R(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}
&=
I
+\alpha^2D(D-\omega \bar{L})^{-1}D(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}\\
&+\alpha D(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}
+\alpha D(D-\omega \bar{L})^{-1}.
\end{split}
$$
This shows nothing yet but if we furthermore assume that the diagonal of $A$ is positive so that we can define the square root $D^{1/2}$ and $D^{-1/2}=(D^{1/2})^{-1}$ of, respectively, $D$ and $D^{-1}$, then
$$
\begin{split}
D^{-1/2}(D-\omega \bar{U})R(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}D^{1/2}
&=
I
+\alpha^2D^{1/2}(D-\omega \bar{L})^{-1}D(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}D^{1/2}\\
&+\alpha D^{1/2}(D-\omega \bar{U})^{-1}D^{1/2}
+\alpha D^{1/2}(D-\omega \bar{L})^{-1}D^{1/2},
\end{split}
$$
which already is symmetric if $A$ is symmetric too.

Note that the assumption that $A$ has positive diagonal is necessary. As an example, if
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 &1 &-1\\
     1 &5& -1\\
     -1 &-1& -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $\omega=1$, the eigenvalues of $R$ are $0$ and $(6\pm 8i)/5$.